# What is the intention behind the product_configurator_settings table?

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api

I am doing some research about variant handling in Shopware in general and was not able to find any relevant information about the table `product_configurator_setting`.

When you create a variant, then it is required to add the relevante property option id, the parent id and the variant id so that there will be a relation created.

```
[
  'id' => $variantUuid,
  'parentId' => $parentUuid,
  'options' => [
      [
          'id' => $propertyGroupOptionId
      ]
  ]
];
```

However, there was an existing documentation which says, that an entry in the table `product_configurator_setting` is required. However, when i create variants in the Shopware-Backend, no such entry is created.

```
  "configuratorSettings" => [
    [
       "productId" => $variantUuid,
       "optionId"  => $propertyGroupOptionId 
   ]
],
```

So for clarification:

1. What is the intention for having the table `product_configurator_setting` and what is the difference to the `options` entry for variants?
2. Isn't the information redundant as it exist for variants?
3. Why is the entry mandatory in the documentation but it will not be created by Shopware when variants are created in the Admin UI.

Answer (score 0):

The product_configurator_setting table in Shopware is used to map product variants to their corresponding configurator options when creating variants programmatically. This is different from the options array used in the Shopware backend to establish the relationship between a variant and its configurator option(s). While the product_configurator_setting table is mentioned as mandatory in some cases, it is not required when creating variants using the Shopware backend.

Comment: This still does not answer the question why it is mandatory in some cases? I do not understand the conceptional reasons behind this. 

It seems redundant for me. The Admin API also only communicates via API, so there should not be any differences.

Comment: It's not redundant. The `options` association only references the property values of a single variant. The conifugrator settings include all property values across all variants and can always be fetched by the parent of a variant. It's needed to build the selection matrix on the product detail page. Otherwise youd'd have to aggregate all options of every variant which can be rather costly performance wise.